# Get in the spirit: The first annual holiday bounty extravaganza - or bountapalooza

Tags: discussion, status-completed, bounty

GTZ to you world builders.

In the spirit of the holidays I have offered up three bounties on some of my older questions.

Please feel free to join me in offering some of your hard earned (... well let's be honest - not that hard) reputation to your fellow world builders.

Happy holidays everyone!

Comment: This is either a great idea, or a great way to waste a lot of Internet points. Either way, what the hell, I'm in.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh Excellent.  Welcome to the dar...hmm... *pointy?* side

Comment: Thanks, I hear you have cook... I mean... bounties.

Comment: For the record, I believe James and I are the top two bounty-givers on Worldbuilding, prior to the start of this. (See [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/372216/top-20-most-generous-users-bounties-awarded), courtesy of [Thomas Weller](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307515/6535830).) Game on, my friend.

Comment: @HDE226868 Wow, we are generous...the rest of you people are stingy.  Bounty up, or santa will be leaving you coal...that's already on fire!

Comment: Hey, you can't make up your bounty points by going over 200 for the day! I got scammed!

Comment: @kingledion I think you missed the generosity point :p

Comment: @HDE226868 I just learned how generous I am

Comment: I did not realize you were doing this when I posted my bounty. Glad I could participate though :)

Comment: @AmaniKilumanga Feel free to add your bounty to the list below.  A record of a first annual holiday tradition! :D

Comment: I just started my first bounty in the spirit of the holidays and this post :D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I figured we might as well keep track of all of this, so I've created a community wiki answer.

## A list of the questions with bounties started during this season:

- [Logic to support specialized kingdom level militaries](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/44486/627), asked and bountied by James (+100)
- [How long would it take a region to geologically settle down after a major cataclysm?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/42177/627), asked and bountied by James (+100)
- [How do I blend cultures - naming world features?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/630/627), asked and bountied by James (+100)
- [Guns vs. Moon Dust](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/63484/627), asked and bountied by DaaaahWhoosh (+100)
- [Natural Projectile Weapons](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/541/627), asked by Tim B and bountied by DaaahWhoosh (+50)
- [Could life exist in a circumstellar disk?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/22872/627), asked and bountied by HDE 226868 (+100)
- [How long does a component of a Dyson swarm spend in shadow?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/62955/627), asked by Werrf and bountied by kingledion (+50)
- [Could a carbon/silicon/oxygen planet exist?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/62303/627), asked by Schafer and bountied by kingledion (+100)
- [What impact is required for a visible (from Earth) ejecta plume on Earth's Moon, and would the Moon survive?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/64753/627), asked by Michael Kjörling  and bountied by Pᴇᴛᴇ (+100)
- [Why would a decision making machine decide to destroy itself?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/64958/627), asked by Dotan Reis and bountied by Amani Kilumanga (+50)
- [Will majority of population dismiss a video of fight between two supernatural beings?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/63517/627), asked and bountied by slobodan.blazeski (+150)
- [Would humans outcompete sequential hermaphrodites?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/57827/627), asked by Yuvato and bountied by slobodan.blazeski (+50)
- [What is the smallest planetary mass that can prevent 'me' from flying off into space?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/64903/627), asked by Mikey and bountied by Mołot (+50)
- [What would this nebula look like from a planet?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/34820/627), asked by Monica Cellio and bountied by HDE 226868 (+100)
- [How does one calculate the tidal heating of a satellite?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/61059/17720), asked by Alexander Ferguson and bountied by Bellerophon (+100)
- [Humans can now run 40 mph. How do I keep the stupid people alive?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/38590/627), asked and bountied by Tres-2b (+50)
- [Why would merfolk have hair?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/42617/627), asked and bountied by Tres-2b (+50)
- [Is Cancer Biologically Universal?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/45612/627), asked and bountied by Tres-2b (+50)
- [The Six-Billion Dollar Man: Oxygen. Do we have the technology?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/28158/627), asked and bountied by Samuel (+200)
- [Measures of power: Nation States](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/65196/627), asked and bountied by James (+100)
- [What would a Boeing 747 look like if it were left in a hangar for 5,000 years. Could it still be flown?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/44994/627), asked by superluminary and bountied by James (+100)
- [Benefits of or reasons why a species would have only one eye?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/37105/627), asked and bountied by Xandar The Zenon (+50)
- [In the future, around year 2500, will only one language exist on earth?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/60033/627), asked and bountied by Amruth A (+100)
- [Can Cloud Nine be built?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/36667/627), asked and bountied by Samuel (+400)
- [Safe way to eat zombies?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/53283/627), asked and bountied by JDługosz (+100)
- [How large can a volcano be?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/12849/627), asked and bountied by HDE 226868 (+50)
- [A culture of lies](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/66212/627), asked and bountied by Erin Thursby (+200)
- [What conditions would an A-type star need to have a blue color?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/66220/627), asked and bountied by Mattias (+50)

---

With the end of [Winter Bash](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/), I think we can call the bountapalooza concluded. In it, we had . . .

- 28 bounties started . . .
- on 28 different questions . . .
- by 16 different users . . .
- for a total of 2,800 reputation points.

That seems to be a pretty big success. Nice job, Worldbuilding!

Comment: It's true, that projectile weapons answer is exemplary :)

Comment: Or just click on “featured” when viewing the question list.

Comment: @JDługosz After the bounties run out, though, that won't be possible. I thought it might be better to have a list even after that, assuming this runs through to the end of Winter Bash.