# The second annual Holiday Bountapalooza

Tags: discussion, status-completed, bounty

Greetings, worldbuilders! It's been a long year of creature-designing, map-making and society-building, and we're now in the throes of [Winter Bash](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/). Last year, to commemorate the holidays, we had [the first annual Bountapalooza](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4186/627). I'd like to propose a second one, starting today and ending probably after Winter Bash ends.

The bountapalooza is all about giving to others - in this case, putting bounties on questions to get more attention to them or reward answers. If you start a bounty, please add it to the community wiki answer below, with the username of the asker, your username, and the number of reputation points for the bounty. I've set things going with a bounty on one of my questions.

Happy holidays, and happy bountying!

Comment: Thanks for getting this posted!

Comment: I've got to say, I'm pretty disappointed by the answers on the bounties I've put out this year. Maybe I next year I should just do one huge bounty :( Anyone reading this, go think of a good answer to some bountied questions!

Comment: @kingledion I've had similar experiences. Part of me wonders if having all of the bounties start within a couple days of each other took attention away from some of the bountied questions - given that we never usually have more than 3-4 bounties at the same time. Maybe a staggered start would work better next time around. Alternatively, it could just be that we've found some of the hardest questions to answer. . . .

Comment: Yeah people could wait to space it out, or, I just added another new one to keep it going :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## A list of the questions with bounties started during this season:

- [Could a large radio telescope survive interstellar spaceflight?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/95380/627), asked and bountied by HDE 226868 (+100)
- [What near-future propulsion system(s) could be employed by my spaceships?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/98601/what-near-future-propulsion-systems-could-be-employed-by-my-spaceships), asked and bountied by dot_Sp0T (+500)
- [How to fire your engines for a near-future trip around the solar system?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/63225/how-to-fire-your-engines-for-a-near-future-trip-around-the-solar-system), asked by kingledion, bountied by dot_Sp0T (+100)
- [Naturally occurring phenomena allowing for hallucinations or "visions"](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/87375/naturally-occurring-phenomena-allowing-for-hallucinations-or-visions), asked and bountied by James (+50)
- [What would it take to build a ship capable of crossing the Pacific?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25272/what-would-it-take-to-build-a-ship-capable-of-crossing-the-pacific), asked by Green, bountied by James (+100)
- [Mounted Cavalry in the Modern Era](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/48735/mounted-cavalry-in-the-modern-era), asked by Nex, bountied by James (+50)
- [How closely should be placed industrial centre / NIMBY from urban centre?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/64080/how-closely-should-be-placed-industrial-centre-nimby-from-urban-centre), asked by Shadow1024, bountied by kingledion (+100)
- [How can I explain a sudden abundance of naturally-occurring beer?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/19808/how-can-i-explain-a-sudden-abundance-of-naturally-occurring-beer), asked by Mikey, bountied by kingledion (+50)
- [Fires in the ventilation shafts of a Dwarven city?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/62902/fired-ventilation-shafts-in-subterranean-dwellings), asked by Bibliophael, bountied by kingledion (+100)
- [How often must carnivorous grassland eat?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/38354/how-often-must-carnivorous-grassland-eat), asked by Joe Bloggs, bountied by Secespitus (+50)
- [Anatomically Correct Griffins](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25281/anatomically-correct-griffins), asked by TrEs-2b, bountied by Secespitus (+50)
- [Anatomically Correct Phoenix](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28458/anatomically-correct-phoenix), asked by TrEs-2b, bountied by Secespitus (+50)
- [How critical is it for life that a planet remains within the habitable zone at all times?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/355/how-critical-is-it-for-life-that-a-planet-remains-within-the-habitable-zone-at-a), asked by Smithkm, bountied by JBH (+100)
- [Are there any free science fiction world settings?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1396/are-there-any-free-science-fiction-world-settings), asked by congusbongus, bountied by JBH (+200)
- [Could you turn the asteroid belt into one giant full spectrum interferometer?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/99549/627), asked by Imipak, bountied by HDE 226868 (+100)
- [Are there any natural forms of communication as robust as speech/vocalization?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/99582/627), asked and bountied by rek (+50)
- [Can you protect a Space Elevator from Space Junk?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/100051/39490), asked by Renzler, bountied by Olga (+100)
- [In a world where two enormous cities are built one on top of the other, what would weather be like in between?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/85294/627), asked and bountied by JanT (+100)
- [A Human Hunter with Sonic Powers?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11610/a-human-hunter-with-sonic-powers), asked and bountied by James (+100)
- [Could a decreased heartrate thanks to better hemoglobin lead to an increased lifespan?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/99714/could-a-decreased-heartrate-thanks-to-better-hemoglobin-lead-to-an-increased-lif), asked and bountied by dot_Sp0T (+150)
- [What is the minimum human population necessary for a sustainable colony?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3/809) asked by Maximillian, bountied by Mołot (+50)
- [How do we create an Anemone Tree?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/100642/627), asked and bountied by James (+50)
- [Would nomadic people stay nomadic even in a temperate climate?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3413/627), asked by Vincent, bountied by JBH (+50)
- [Best platform for collaborative worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3267/627), asked by Envite, bountied by JBH (+100)
- [How efficient can my neutrino detector be?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/100169/627), asked and bountied by HDE 226868 (+200)
- [Are there physiological traits common to all tool-building species?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/100986/627), asked and bountied by JBH (+200)

---

This year's bountapalooza was quite something. We had . . .

- 26 bounties started . . .
- on 26 different questions . . .
- by 11 different users . . .
- for a total of 2850 reputation points.

For the second year in a row, nice job, Worldbuilding!