# The third annual Holiday Bountapalooza

Tags: discussion, bounty

---------------------  [image] -------------------------

### ***Come one come all, to the third annual share your imaginary internet points party!***

Jussssst in case this isn't entirely clear, an explanation, which I shamelessly stole from HDE:

---

The bountapalooza is all about giving to others - in this case, putting bounties on questions to give them more attention or to reward particularly excellent answers.

**If you start a bounty, please add it to the community wiki answer below, with the username of the asker, your username, and the number of reputation points for the bounty.**

We generally run bountapalooza throughout [winter bash](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask#)

Happy holidays, and happy world building, its been a weird/entertaining year :)

---

If you are curious here are links to the previous two years' bountapaloozas

[2016/2017](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4186/get-in-the-spirit-the-first-annual-holiday-bounty-extravaganza-or-bountapaloo)

[2017/2018](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5675/the-second-annual-holiday-bountapalooza)

Comment: I'm curious to see if we can break the 3000-reputation-points-offered barrier this year. We've come close both times in the past (2800 and 2850). We're almost halfway as of this morning (1400). . .

Answer (score 6):

## A list of the questions with bounties started during this season:

- [Shattering Swords: Yea or Nay?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/111874/shattering-swords-aye-or-nay), asked by [Liquid](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/39934/liquid) and bountied by [James](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/189/james), (+100)
- [What are some ways mass changing of terrain in a short period of time could occur?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/133/what-are-some-ways-mass-changing-of-terrain-in-a-short-period-of-time-could-occu), asked by [Absinthe](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/89/absinthe) and bountied by [JBH](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/40609/jbh), (+100)
- [Food requirements for Localised Temporal Fields, at different time velocities?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/49171/food-requirements-for-localised-temporal-fields-at-different-time-velocities), asked by [EveryBitHelps](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/21839/everybithelps) and bountied by [JBH](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/40609/jbh), (+100)
- [Can someone help me with ocean currents? I'm really confused](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/132286/can-someone-help-me-with-ocean-currents-im-really-confused), asked by [Tristan Henderson](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/53821/tristan-henderson) and bountied by [JBH](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/40609/jbh), (+150)
- [Would it be possible to farm the energy from pulsars?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/110095/627), asked by [Sievert](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/49893/sievert) and bountied by [HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/627/hde-226868) (+100)
- [Why buy tech from the future?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/114363/why-buy-tech-from-the-future), asked by [Green](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10364/green) and bountied by [Green](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10364/green), (+100)
- [Can magnetism be what causes my flat Earth to accelerate?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/132912/can-magnetism-be-what-causes-my-flat-earth-to-accelerate), asked by [chasly from UK](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10759/chasly-from-uk) and bountied by [Dubukay](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/43163/dubukay) (+100)
- [How to prevent electronic advancement beyond the early cold war era?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/132670/809) asked by [arlilo](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/58271/arlilo) and bountied by [Mołot](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/809/mo%C5%82ot) (+50)
- [Do different star systems experience time differently?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/4962/627), asked by [Twelfth](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/288/twelfth) and bountied by [Renan](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/21222/renan) (+500)
- [What would the sky look like in the SHADOW of planetary rings?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/66681/627), asked by [bciga22322](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/31741/bciga22322) and bountied by [HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/627/hde-226868) (+100)
- [How large does a spacecraft need to be to be visible from the surface of the Earth at 400 km altitude?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3768/809) asked by [Kami](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/870/kami) and bountied by [Mołot](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/809/mo%C5%82ot) (+50)
- [Solar recycling or: How to keep your star from dying](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/134250/solar-recycling-or-how-to-keep-your-star-from-dying), asked by [James](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/189/james) and bountied by James (+50)
- [How dangerous is a 500-year-old nuclear warhead?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/132546/how-dangerous-is-a-500-year-old-nuclear-warhead), asked by [zwol](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/24998/zwol) and bountied by Hosch250 (+100)
- [Habitability of a planet with highly variable temperatures](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/134321/habitability-of-a-planet-with-highly-variable-temperatures) asked by [Gabe](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/52369/gabe-l) and bountied by James (+100)
- [Given our current knowledge of exoplanets, approximately how many planets have earth-like gravity in a galaxy the size of the Milky Way?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/85957/627), asked by [Corwin62](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/40417/corwin62) and bountied by [HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/627/hde-226868) (+100)
- [How can I make a black dwarf star?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/117297/627), asked by [HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/627/hde-226868) and bountied by [HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/627/hde-226868) (+100)
- [Could Earth and the Moon be the same size?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/101045/627), asked by [kingledion](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/23519/kingledion) and bountied by [HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/627/hde-226868) (+100)
- [Reactions to a Young Time Traveller](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/135175/627), asked by [Tanzanite Dragoness](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/56319/tanzanite-dragoness) and bountied by [Tanzanite Dragoness](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/56319/tanzanite-dragoness) (+50)
- [Does my plot point centered around eclipses make sense?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/135178/627), asked by [DoctorJerk](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/53067/doctorjerk) and bountied by [Rowyn Alloway](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/57654/rowyn-alloway) (+50)
- [Are there logical gaps in the periodic table in which you could insert a new mystery element for use as a fuel?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/37077/627), asked by [James](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/189/james) and bountied by [HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/627/hde-226868) (+100)
- [A Roman-technology clock run by slaves - how to make it accurate](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/135487/627), asked by [chasly from UK](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10759/chasly-from-uk) and bountied by [chasly from UK](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10759/chasly-from-uk) (+500)
- [Could the Sun be born again?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/114395/627), asked by [HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/627/hde-226868) and bountied by [HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/627/hde-226868) (+100)

---

As always, here are the final bountapalooza stats:

- 22 bounties started . . .
- on 22 different questions . . .
- by 11 different users . . .
- for a total of 2700 reputation points.

Nice job, everyone! Happy holidays!

Comment: Apparently 3000 is a goal we will have to strive for again next year! :D