# Will we have a Holiday Bountapalooza this year?

Tags: discussion, bounty

The holiday bountapolooza is (was... shall be again...) an invitation to search for and place bounties on deserving questions and/or answers. It not only helps get people in the mood to post bounties periodically, but it also enlivens user participation.

- **Let's do this!** (2023)
- Out of habit? (2022)
- Pandemic (2021)
- Pandemic (2020)
- [The fourth annual holiday bountapalooza](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7662/40609) (2019)
- [The third annual Holiday Bountapalooza](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6958/40609) (2018)
- [The second annual Holiday Bountapalooza](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5675/40609) (2017)
- [Get in the spirit: The first annual holiday bounty extravaganza - or bountapalooza](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4186/40609) (2016)

Comment: What even is this?

Comment: @elemtilas Did we not examine the linked Meta posts? ;-) The holiday bountapolooza is (was... shall be again...) an invitation to search for and place bounties on deserving questions and/or answers. It not only helps get people in the mood to post bounties periodically, but it also enlivens user participation.

Comment: I'll be over-pedantic in place of Elemtilas . Topics should hold themselves alone. I suggest you add a 2 or 3 line explanations of the event along with its history ^^.

Comment: Why not ? Just with a better name hopefully

Comment: @JBH --- Touché! So long as this becomes the Eighth Annual!

Comment: Did we forget? I'm afraid I did.

Comment: @KeizerHarm Dang nabit. We forgot. Despite that I posted three bounties for Santa questions. By all means, if there are any 1-3 deserving questions out there, spread the cheer and a little rep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [coiner of the term "bountapalooza"](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/17213?m=34218179#34218179) and longtime advocate of the event, I think bringing it back is a great idea.

The holiday bountapalooza originated in 2016, when [James was feeling extra generous](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/17213?m=34216787#34216787) during the holiday season, and caught on when it became clear that we were a weirdly competitive bunch when it came to offering the most bounties. Participation stayed steady for several more annual iterations, until larger network-wide events in 2019 drove down activity in general on the site, and we didn't bring it back for 2020 -- I don't think anyone even suggested it:

- 2016: 28 bounties, by 16 users, for 2800 points
- 2017: 26 bounties, by 11 users, for 2850 points
- 2018: 22 bounties, by 11 users, for 2700 points
- 2019: 15 bounties, by 12 users, for 1600 points

I think it'll be hard to reach the heights we achieved those first three years, but this year is particularly opportune because [Stack Exchange will no longer be holding Winterbash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392846/274942). Reviving the bountapalooza is a great chance to resuscitate the fun that we always had with Winterbash.

Comment: I'll pledge 1000 of my Internet Points, so we'll reach at least 2/3rds of the heights of 2019 by one measure.

Answer (score 3):

### I won't participate...

I won't join in the event because my daily activities don't bring me up a lot of points to spend. At the same time, I really want the new privilege because I'm curiously sick -or sickly curious- of not being able to see deleted posts. I'm already not very fast and furious over earning points, so if I'm running on the bounty treadmill, too ...

That being said, this doesn't mean the event should not exist, I'm just personally out for this one. If a few people is willing to spend a few SE bucks on such event however, it will absolutely bring some interest to this site.

Comment: Cheers. There's never an obligation to participate. Unsurprisingly, it tended to be frequented by people with 50K+ rep. But what it does it give people with <2k rep (notably) an encouraging chance to boost their rep by getting involved with answers and, to a lesser degree, to get them to post bountiable (if that's a word) questions.